# Get url parameter: How to convert URL specific parameters to array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to convert url specific parameters to array? I have used many types or parameter. I have tried below code with `var types = ['A', 'C'];` and its working.

But it's not working with url. I need to get `community` parameter from URL. How to convert url parameters to array? like this `var types = ['business_center','wireless_access'];`

```
http://demo/apartments/?price-min=200&price-max=2356&bedroom=3&bathroom=2&ap_features%5B%5D=washer+%26+dryer+connections&ap_features%5B%5D=dishwasher&community%5B%5D=business_center&community%5B%5D=clubhouse&community%5B%5D=covered_parking&submit=SEARCH

//var types = ['A', 'C'];
var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf('?');
document.location.href.substr(i+1).replace(/community=/g,'').split('&');
$('input[name="community[]"]').prop('checked', function() {
  return $.inArray(this.value, types) !== -1;
});
```

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @xianshenglu var types = ['business_center','wireless_access'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the query string with `document.location.search`. Then use this snippet to get all the query string values. So with this result array you can filter or similar what you want. Is this what you looking for?

```js
var url = '?price-min=200&price-max=2356&bedroom=3&bathroom=2&ap_features%5B%5D=washer+%26+dryer+connections&ap_features%5B%5D=dishwasher&community%5B%5D=business_center&community%5B%5D=clubhouse&community%5B%5D=covered_parking&submit=SEARCH';
var final = url.replace('?','').split('&').map(x=> x.split('=')[1]);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the URL and make a JSON object out of it.
Parameters will become keys and their values will be stored in a corresponding array.

```js
var url = 'http://demo/apartments/?price-min=200&price-max=2356&bedroom=3&bathroom=2&ap_features%5B%5D=washer+%26+dryer+connections&ap_features%5B%5D=dishwasher&community%5B%5D=business_center&community%5B%5D=clubhouse&community%5B%5D=covered_parking&submit=SEARCH';

var ob = URLToArray(url);
console.log(ob); //output the whole key-value pair object
console.log(ob["community"]); //obtain the "community" values (Array)

function URLToArray(url) {
  var request = {};
  var pairs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    if (!pairs[i]) //if empty parameter then continue to next
      continue;
    var pair = pairs[i].split('='); //split to separate values
    if (pair[0].indexOf('%') > -1) //community has some string attached to it starting with %, this cleans it
      pair[0] = pair[0].substring(0, (pair[0].indexOf('%')));
    var key = pair[0];
    if (key in request) //check if any value with same key is already stored
      request[key].push(pair[1]); //append to the array of already existing values
    else
      request[key] = [pair[1]]; //else make a new key-value pair, value is an array of elements
  }
  return request;
}
```

Comment: Wow this was really helpful. Thanks!